# Unexpected result c while

Tags: c, testing

Hi im trying to understand why if 9 or above is entered for judge it passes but it shouldnt cause the if says >= 4 and <= 8

Thanks

```
while(!(judge >= 4) && (judge <= 8))
{
    printf("How many judges are there ? Enter a number between 4 - 8 \n");
    scanf("%d", &judge);
    while(!(judge >= 4) && (judge <= 8))
    {
        printf("You entered %d Enter a number between 4 - 8 \n", judge);
        scanf("%d", &judge);
        if((judge >= 4) && (judge <= 8))
        {
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean passes?

Comment: classic paranthese and operator precedence mistake..`!` only for first condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing a pair of parentheses in

```
while(!((judge >= 4) && (judge <= 8)))
       ^                            ^
```

(This mistake appears in two places.)

By the way, you can avoid a lot of the repetition by restructuring your code like so:

```
printf("How many judges are there ? Enter a number between 4 - 8 \n");
for (;;) {
    scanf("%d", &judge);
    if (judge >= 4 && judge <= 8) {
        break;
    }
    printf("You entered %d Enter a number between 4 - 8 \n", judge);
}
```